# Read file from virtual directory that is poiting to a file server

Tags: asp.net, iis

Im hosting an asp.net website on IIS, I created a virtual directory that is poiting to another server where I store the files.

If I put in browser url like:

http://10.10.10.10/files/01/1111/name%20of%20file%20.pdf, the file opens.

How do I read the file using c#

Answer (score 1):

The way this works?

code behind = plane jane fully windows path name.

Any web page - a correctly formed URL.

So, you mapped that virtual folder to a plane jane fully legal windows path name.

So, your code behind ALWAYS uses standard windows path names.

So, you have to convert a given URL path name to internal.

So, say you have this:

```
  http://10.10.10.10/files/01/1111/nameoffile.pdf
```

You thus go

```
string MyURL = "http://10.10.10.10/files/01/1111/nameoffile.pdf";

string MyWindowsFilePath = Server.MapPath(MyURL);
```

At this point, MyWindowsFilePath will be the full plane jane windows path name to the mapped virtual folder.

so you can go:

```
bytes[] MyBinFile;
MyBinFile = File.ReadBinaryFile(MyWindowsFilePath);
```

So, a simple rule is to just remember that any web page expressions - they are URL based. But any code behind uses plane jane windows file names - that code behind is not really any different then say writing desktop code.

And thus Server.MapPath() will translate the URL path give to that plane jane good old fashioned windows file path name.